# jquery.width() and jquery.height sometimes work wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to loop all img tags and put three 25*25 pixel images on the center on all `images` triangularly.
Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jengge/xhjvvhu2/1/)

And if you want to know how it works please check this url.
http://tag-test-super-star.c9users.io

This sometimes work correctly but sometimes work wrong.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem? No triangulars at all? They are not centered? They have the wrong size? Triangulars doesn't appear on all images, only on some.

Comment: I mean not triangle. I mean I want to put three 25*25 images triangularly.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood that. But still, what doesn't work? Is only one 25x25 images added? Two? Are they not centered? Are they not added to all images?

Comment: It works well but sometimes three images doesn't be centered correctly.

Comment: If you want to see how it works please check this url. http://tag-test-super-star.c9users.io

Comment: You probably aren't waiting for images to load in order to get their dimensions. Please post relevant code in the question ... your link will rot over time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait until the images are loaded.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    //some code
})
```